# How to add multiple images to XSSFGroupShape

Tags: apache-poi

Trying to add multiple images to `XSSFGroupShape`. I have tried the following(modified for simplicity):

```java
    import lombok.Getter;
    import lombok.Setter;
    import lombok.experimental.Accessors;

    private void addImagesToGroupShape(Sheet sheet, List<XSSFGroupImage> groupImages) throws Exception{
        // XSSFGroupShape dimension
        int dx1 = 180975;
        int dy1 = 409575;
        int dx2 = 219075;
        int dy2 = 638175;
        int row1 = 9;
        int col1 = 8;
        int row2 = 38;
        int col2 = 19;
        XSSFDrawing drawing = (XSSFDrawing) sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
        XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(dx1, dy1, dx2, dy2, col1, row1, col2, row2);
        XSSFShapeGroup shapeGroup = drawing.createGroup(anchor);
        
        // XSSFGroupImage is a custom class
        // Included below
        for (XSSFGroupImage groupImage : groupImages) {
            byte[] imageData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(groupImage.data().getBytes());
            
            int picType = 1;
            switch (groupImage.extension()) {
            case "jpeg":
                picType = Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG;
                break;
            case "png":
                picType = Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG;
                break;
            case "emf":
                picType = Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_EMF;
                break;
            default:
                var msg = "Extension not supported";
                throw new Exception(msg);
            }

            int pictureIndex = sheet.getWorkbook().addPicture(imageData, picType);
           
            // shapeGroup.createPicture(anchor, pictureIndex);

            CTPicture ctPic = shapeGroup.getCTGroupShape().insertNewPic(pictureIndex);

            CTTransform2D ct2D = ctPic.addNewSpPr().addNewXfrm();
            ct2D.addNewOff();
            ct2D.addNewExt();

            ct2D.getOff().setX(groupImage.offsetX());
            ct2D.getOff().setY(groupImage.offsetY());
            ct2D.getExt().setCx(Long.parseLong(groupImage.extentsCx()));
            ct2D.getExt().setCy(Long.parseLong(groupImage.extentsCy()));

            XSSFChildAnchor childAnchor = new XSSFChildAnchor(Integer.parseInt(groupImage.offsetX()),
                    Integer.parseInt(groupImage.offsetY()), Integer.parseInt(groupImage.extentsCx()),
                    Integer.parseInt(groupImage.extentsCy()));

            // shapeGroup.getCTGroupShape().addNewPic();
            // shapeGroup.createPicture(childAnchor, picIndex);

            // ctPic.addNewBlipFill().addNewBlip().setEmbed("");
        }
    }

    @Accessors(fluent = true)
    public class XSSFGroupImage {
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private String data;
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private String extension;
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private String offsetX;
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private String offsetY;
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private String extentsCx;
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private String extentsCy;
    }
```

[Added images outside group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44755977/insert-image-into-excel-with-apache-poi) and [retrieved properties and data of embedded images from group shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760635/get-all-shapes-in-shapegroup).

I understand the fact that an image cannot attached without an `anchor`. However, I couldn't find a way of adding an `XSSFChildAnchor` inside the `XSSFGroupShape` that would allow setting of properites of `CTTransform2D` object.

I also tried to add the image to the `Workbook` using `int pictureIndex = sheet.getWorkbook().addPicture(imageData, picType)` and use that index to set the `CTPicture` using `shapeGroup.getCTGroupShape().insertNewPic(pictureIndex)`. However, by doing this the `relationId` that would point to that image is not being set resulting in no image being displayed.

[Image of desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TLX0.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XSSFShapeGroup` is not complete until now (`apache 5.0.0` May 2021).

But if pictures shall be in that group then those pictures first must be created at workbook level using `Workbook.addPicture`. There is no way around.

Having the picture ids then one can put the pictures in the group using  [XSSFShapeGroup.createPicture](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.0/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFShapeGroup.html#createPicture-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor-int-). There the `XSSFClientAnchor` is useless until now and can be simply `new XSSFClientAnchor()`. Nevertheless what else is set for that `XSSFClientAnchor` it will not have effect, neither for size of picture nor for position in the group. So after `XSSFPicture picture = shapeGroup.createPicture(new XSSFClientAnchor(), pictureIdx1);` the `picture` will be at position 0, 0 and will be of size 0, 0.

The size can be set using `XSSFPicture.resize`. If that is not possible, then it would must be calculated in unit `EMU` and set using low level `ooxml` classes. For example along the lines of

```java
...
XSSFPicture picture = shapeGroup.createPicture(new XSSFClientAnchor(), pictureIdx1);
picture.getCTPicture().getSpPr().getXfrm().getExt().setCx(widthInEMU);
picture.getCTPicture().getSpPr().getXfrm().getExt().setCy(heightInEMU);
...
```

The position must be set using low level `ooxml` classes. For position X and Y also `EMU` is  the measurement unit. For example:

```java
...
picture.getCTPicture().getSpPr().getXfrm().getOff().setX(xInEMU);
picture.getCTPicture().getSpPr().getXfrm().getOff().setY(yInEMU);
...
```

So knowing that, let's provide a complete example. The following works (tested) using `apache poi 5.0.0`. Please note: The native size of the image files `image1.jpeg` and `image2.jpeg` should not be bigger than the anchor for the group frame.

```java
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class CreateExcelXSSFShapeGroup {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

  //add picture data to this workbook.
  FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("./image1.jpeg");
  byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
  int pictureIdx1 = workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
  is.close();
  is = new FileInputStream("./image2.jpeg");
  bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
  int pictureIdx2 = workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
  is.close();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");

  Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

  //From here on XSSF only.
  XSSFDrawing xssfdrawing = (XSSFDrawing)drawing;
  XSSFClientAnchor anchor = (XSSFClientAnchor)helper.createClientAnchor();

  int groupShapeStartsAtCol = 1;
  int groupShapeStartsAtRow = 1;
  anchor.setCol1(groupShapeStartsAtCol);
  anchor.setRow1(groupShapeStartsAtRow); 
  int groupWidthInCols = 8;
  anchor.setCol2(groupShapeStartsAtCol + groupWidthInCols);
  int groupHeightInRows = 20;
  anchor.setRow2(groupShapeStartsAtRow + groupHeightInRows);

  XSSFShapeGroup shapeGroup = xssfdrawing.createGroup(anchor); // group shape is now of size from anchor abowe

  XSSFPicture picture = shapeGroup.createPicture(new XSSFClientAnchor(), pictureIdx1);
  //picture.resize(); // picture is now at pos 0, 0 (top left) of group shape and of it's native size
  picture.getCTPicture().getSpPr().getXfrm().getExt().setCx(1234567);
  picture.getCTPicture().getSpPr().getXfrm().getExt().setCy(1234567); // picture is now at pos 0, 0 (top left) of group shape and of size 1234567 x 1234567 EMU
  
  picture = shapeGroup.createPicture(new XSSFClientAnchor(), pictureIdx2);
  picture.resize(); // picture is now at pos 0, 0 (top left) of group shape and of it's native size

  // picture shall be at position bottom right of group shape
  // so top left of picture must be at x = group width - picture width and y = group height - picture height
  int pictureWidthInPx = (int)Math.round(picture.getImageDimension().getWidth());
  int pictureHeightInPx = (int)Math.round(picture.getImageDimension().getHeight());
  int defaultColWidthInPx = Math.round(sheet.getColumnWidthInPixels(0));
  int defaultRowHeightInPx = Units.pointsToPixel(sheet.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints()); 
 
  int xInEMU = Units.pixelToEMU(groupWidthInCols * defaultColWidthInPx - pictureWidthInPx);
  picture.getCTPicture().getSpPr().getXfrm().getOff().setX(xInEMU);
  int yInEMU = Units.pixelToEMU(groupHeightInRows * defaultRowHeightInPx - pictureHeightInPx);
  picture.getCTPicture().getSpPr().getXfrm().getOff().setY(yInEMU);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelXSSFShapeGroup.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: It didn't occur to me that `XSSFClientAnchor` was useless. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped, I was trying to use XSSFClientAnchor and spent probably 2 hours. Your answer helped a lot.